# Mysql insert where select exist

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help with my mysql query. I try to insert into products where currency if exist.
In php code this query show like this

```
$q = "select * from currency where type = ".$input." limit 1";

    if(mysql_query($q)){
    $q2= "insert into product ("cur","cur_type","val") VALUE ($q['id'], $q['type'],$price)";
    if(mysql_query($q2)){

    echo "success";
    }
    }
```

and like this, but how i make this code in one query ? Can you help me write query who insert input values where exist currency in other table ?
Thank you

Comment: Don't use mysql_query. use PDO instead. Bobby tables will thank you. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Yes, I'm using PDO but code is too long to paste on this site :)

Comment: Now you're just being silly. PDO is not longer than `mysql_` functions.

Comment: okey, but i'm using pdo in this way: $sth = $this->db->prepare ( "$query" ); $sth->rowCount; $sth->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ). It is enough? thanks :)

Comment: No you need to bind your parameters as well., see: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php `<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement to comine an insert with select. Pls note, you should not be using mysql_*() functions any longer, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo instead.

The sql will look like sg the following:

```
insert into product (cur,cur_type,val)
select id, type, $price from currency where type=$input
```

However, you need to write the php part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use such query.

```
"INSERT INTO pruduct (cur,cur_type,val)
SELECT id,type, {$price} AS embeded_price FROM currency WHERE type='{$input}'LIMIT 1";
```